# Deutsche Tonalität

Tags: pronunciation

Ich bin Spanier, bin auch in Spanien aufgewachsen, und habe etwa mit zwölf Jahren angefangen, Deutsch zu lernen, was mir immer sehr viel Spaß gemacht hat. Seit ein paar Jahren lebe ich auch hier in Deutschland, und damals, als ich hier eingezogen bin, konnte ich zum Glück Deutsch gut genug, dass die Sprache eigentlich nie ein Problem gewesen wäre.

Inzwischen haben sich meine Deutschkenntnisse natürlich sehr verbessert, und meine Deutsche Freunde hier meinen sogar, dass ich kaum (und wenn, dann sehr, sehr selten) grammatikalische Fehler, oder ähnliche begehe. Sie behaupten nur, man würde trotzdem ziemlich schnell erkennen, dass ich eben kein Muttersprachler bin. Das soll nicht unbedingt an der Aussprache der einzelnen Phoneme liegen, sondern vielmehr an der (spanischen) Tonalität, die ich auf natürliche Weise verwende und die viel melodischer ist, als sie sollte. Laut meinen Freunden wird Deutsch eher »flach« betont, so dass es sich bei mir so anhört, als würde ich ständig versuchen, Dinge zu betonen.

Mein Problem ist nun, dass ich es nicht einmal bemerke, selbst wenn ich mir Sprachnachrichten von mir anhöre, und daher auch nicht weiß, wie ich meine spanische Tonalität überhaupt aktiv verändern könnte, um sie »flacher« zu machen ...

Gibt es irgendwelche Methoden oder Kurse, die dieses Problem angehen / sich hiermit befassen? Das fängt an, ein wenig frustrierend zu werden :/

---

I'm Spanish, I also grew up in Spain, and I started learning German around the age of twelve, which was always a lot of fun. For a few years now, I have also been living here in Germany, and back then, when I moved here, I luckily knew German well enough that the language would never have actually been a problem.

In the meantime, my German skills have improved a lot, of course, and my German friends here even think that I hardly (and if, then very, very rarely) make grammatical mistakes, or the like. They only claim that one would still immediately recognize that I am not a native speaker. This is not necessarily because of the pronunciation of the individual phonemes, but rather because of the tonality I use in a natural way, which is supposed to be much more melodic than it should. According to my friends, German is stressed "flat", so it all sounds like I'm constantly trying to emphasize things.

My problem now is that I don't even notice it, even when I listen to voice messages of mine, and thus don't know how to even change my Spanish tonality to make it more "flat"...

Are there any methods or courses that address this? This is starting to get a little frustrating :/

Comment: Keine Antwort, aber: Es ist unwahrscheinlich, dass man die in der Kindheit gelernte Sprachmelodie einer melodischen romanischen Sprache jemals wieder "los wird". Ich habe einen in Spanien aufgewachsenen Kollegen mit deutschen Eltern, der absolut perfektes Deutsch spricht, aber "man hört es trotzdem". Freu' dich an deiner romanischen Sprachmelodie und sei stolz darauf - als spanischer Muttersprachler so perfekt Deutsch zu können, dass man es nur noch an der Melodie erkennt, ist mehr "Leistung", als es wie ein deutscher Muttersprachler "einfach so" zu können und sich auch so anzuhören.

Comment: @tofro: I was about to make a similar comment. Becoming fluent in a second language is much more rare in the US than in Europe. I don't know what the general attitude is toward foreign accents is in Germany compared to the US. But I  do know that here people just accept the fact that people from other places tend to speak differently. I've watched a lot of German learning videos and the instructors all speak English with, to me, thick German accents, despite, I assume, years of studying English. As long as you can be understood I don't see that there's a problem.

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, I'm not sure that it's on-topic for the site. Perhaps the [Language Learning SE](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: Mir geht es umgekehrt. Ich bin Deutscher und lebe seit über 20 Jahren in Catalunya. Bin nach zweiwöchigem Spanisch-Intensivkurs hierhergezogen und habe Catalán über den täglichen Umgang aufgeschnappt. In den eher touristischen Gegenden an der Küste werde ich bis heute, einfach aufgrund des nicht-spanischen Aussehens, manchmal in den Geschäften auf Englisch angesprochen. Mein Spanisch/Catalán? Der *subjuntivo* klappt, *ser/estar* auch - die typischen Probleme für jemanden, der keine romanische Muttersprache hat, verschwinden schnell. Aber den Ausländer hört man: Das "ll" und die weicheren Konso

Answer (score 3):

Vielleicht bist du in gewisser Hinsicht Opfer des eigenen Erfolges: Dadurch, dass die Verständlichkeit nie ein Problem war, gab es keinen Grund, an der Natürlichkeit zu arbeiten.

Die Melodie einer Sprache nehmen Babys schon im Mutterleib auf und sie wird auch von Geburt an von ihnen [reproduziert](https://www.mpg.de/572636/pressemitteilung20091105). Das ist aber kein Grund, zu glauben, dass man nicht auch noch im Erwachsenenalter an der Aussprache arbeiten kann. Die Grundstrategien sind Bewusstmachung und Imitation: Man muss lernen, die relevanten Merkmal wahrzunehmen und nachzumachen. Das klingt erst einmal sehr abstrakt und die meisten Erwachsenen (wie sich auch in den Kommentaren zeigt) sind in Bezug auf die Erfolgsaussichten ziemlich skeptisch.

Man kann aber umgekehrt darauf verweisen, wie vielen Menschen es sogar ohne bewusstes Training gelingt, ihre Aussprache anzupassen (z.B. wenn sie im Lauf der Zeit den Dialekt ihrer Heimat verlieren und den ihres aktuellen Wohnortes annehmen). Mir ist in den USA einmal ein in Deutschland geborener und aufgewachsener Mann begegnet, der Deutsch nur noch mit amerikanischer Satzmelodie sprechen konnte.

In den meisten Lehrwerken spielt die Aussprache eine untergeordnete Rolle. Ein Buch, dass sich speziell diesem Thema widmet, ist *[77 Klangbilder](https://www.schubert-verlag.de/klangbilder.php)* von Wolfgang Rug. Wie der Blick ins Inhaltsverzeichnis zeigt, ist das Thema Sprechmelodie leider ganz ans Ende des Buchs gerückt und auf wenige Seiten beschränkt. Aber es wäre sicherlich ein Anfang.

Answer (score 3):

Unabhängig davon, ob es wirklich sinnvoll oder notwendig ist, dass Du diese Mühe auf Dich nimmst, möchte ich mal Deine eigentliche Frage beantworten:

> Gibt es irgendwelche Methoden oder Kurse, die dieses Problem angehen / sich hiermit befassen?

Grundsätzlich ja, aber ich denke in diesem Fall ist es mit einem einfachen »Kurs« nicht getan, sondern Du musst einen Sprach-/Stimmlehrer bemühen, der mit Dir daran arbeitet und genau auf Deine Bedürfnisse eingeht. Dein »Problem« geht ja schon in Richtung Training für Theaterschauspieler oder Radiosprecher, die sich auf der Bühne/vorm Mikrofon ganz anders artikulieren müssen als sie es im Alltag in ihrer natürlichen Sprache tun.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Bayer hat eine andere Sprachmelodie als ein Schwabe, Rheinländer, Sachse, Friese. Im Spanischen wird das vermutlich entsprechend sein.

Was für ein Ziel will man sich da als Deutschlerner setzen? Dass man klingt wie jemand, der in den 1980ern in Wanne-Eickel aufgewachsen ist? Das hätte ja nichts mehr mit Sprachlernen zu tun, das wäre Imitation. Einem Norddeutschen, der in München versucht, wie ein Bayer zu klingen, wird dafür kein Respekt gezeugt, sondern eher im Gegenteil -- denn er gibt auf, was er ist, um etwas anderes vorzutäuschen.

Warum soll ich im Englischen klingen wie ein Mitglied der 2%, die Received Pronuciation sprechen? Oder wie ein Kalifornier? Warum nicht wie ein Deutscher, der mit jahrelanger Anstrengung neben seiner Muttersprache so gutes Englisch gelernt hat, dass er sich ausdrücken kann und verstanden wird?

Wenn man in die Sprache eintaucht und sie viel hört, ergibt sich mit der Zeit von selbst eine Aussprache, mit der man auch verstanden wird. *Das* finde ich wichtig. Ich möchte eine Sprache so sprechen können, dass nicht nur Deutsche mich versehen, sondern auch Einheimische. Ich möchte verstehen, was gesagt wird, mich ausdrücken können, verstanden werden und idealerweise als kompetent in der Sprache gesehen werden.

Das Ziel, ununterscheidbar zu klingen wie ein Einheimischer, ist ein leider in der Lehre von Sprachen immer wieder hochgehaltenes, aber kaum zu erreichendes und letztlich m.E. nicht wichtiges Ziel.

Comment: "Warum soll ich im Englischen klingen wie ein Mitglied... Warum nicht wie ein Deutscher?" Weil Akzente ziemlich anstrengend zum Zuhören sein können. Und das gilt jetzt nicht nur für einen deutschen Akzent. Man denke z. B. an einen französischen Akzent.

Comment: @idmean Das kommt zu 100% darauf an, wie stark er ist. Das Level, bei dem die Aussprache gut verständlich ist, ist wie gesagt schon wichtig zu erreichen. Ich rede hier über den Satz aus der Frage: "Sie behaupten nur, man würde trotzdem ziemlich schnell erkennen, dass ich eben kein Muttersprachler bin."